# How to rebase a branch while keeping the rebase target changes intact?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a repository that has two branches named `develop` and `pythonClient`, with the former hosting C# code and the latter hosting a python port. Both codebases are located in different folders to maintain a clear separation.

The `pythonClient` branch was created off `develop` a month and a half ago and it hasn't been synced up with `develop` since, but now I need to rebase it so it has all the latest C# code. I am trying to achieve this with the following commands:

```
git checkout pythonClient
git rebase develop
```

I was expecting the rebase to apply cleanly, since `pythonClient` hasn't changed any C# code at all, yet I keep seeing conflicts on some `.csproj` files. Am I misunderstanding what a rebase really does, or how the command must be executed? - On the other hand, I'd rather tell git to ignore any collision and just prefer whatever the C#/`develop` branch has as this rebase may not affect that folder at all, how may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that `pythonClient` did not change any C# code (files in `develop`), hence why you are seeing a conflict. But what you are looking for is an additional parameter for your rebase command: `theirs` vs `ours`

So when you are on `pythonClient` branch, and in the case of `rebase`, do:

`git rebase -X ours develop`

This will achieve exactly what you are asking for: "*I'd rather tell git to ignore any collision and just prefer whatever the `C#/develop` branch has*"

Comment: `git log --follow "csharpFolder"` outputs commits up to the point `pythonClient` diverged from `develop` - I sincerely don't know why git is freaking out and issuing confllcts.

Comment: @Machinarius Did you try inspecting the history of the .csproj on `pythonClient`? It should show you commits on the file then you can diff with `develop`. But this is another issue, for now you can run the command with the additional parameter and you will be good to go.

Comment: I ran the rebase as you suggested and no conflicts were reported, though a lot of empty commits were generated. Comparing the csharp folder between the `python` and `develop` branches  after that rebase yielded some very old code differences, could a `git push --force` have caused this?

Comment: @Kahlil Khalaf You are correct, I did unintentionally bring commits from develop into PythonClient before today. Though luck, I guess.

Comment: For future reference, I ended up indentifying where I really started work on the python client and created a new branch with just that by running `git rebase -X theirs --onto develop python_work_started python_work_ended` - That managed to produce a branch that outputs an empty diff both from `develop` and `pythonClient` on the respective folders. Fortunately, once I started work on python on that branch no more C# code was put in it.